# Help identifying a moth

Tags: species-identification, entomology

It looks like it might be an emerald moth but its hard to tell from the discoloration in the wings and it is too high up for me to get a better look.

When: July 23rd 2018

Where: Central Illinois

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like an Imperial Moth (*Eacles imperialis*):

[image]

Source: https://www.butterfliesandmoths.org/species/Eacles-imperialis

As shown on the distribution map at this link, they can be found in central Illinois.